# How to position element behind text in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a page with a simple Bootstrap Jumbotron at the top:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <h1>My fancy map site</h1>
        <p>Some stuff here</p>
        <p><a href="somePage'" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">I'm a button</a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I would like to do is embed an element as a background in the Jumbotron, more specifically a map (probably Google maps). How do I position it inside the Jumbotron but behind everything else?

Probably something with relative positions, but css really isn't my strong point.

Answer (score 0):

check this JsFiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/ravk26/ApSC3/

Here is the html and css:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron">
<div class="container">
    <div class="map"><iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d26081603.294420436!2d-95.677068!3d37.06250000000001!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1395991829737" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe></div>
    <h1>My fancy map site</h1>
    <p>Some stuff here</p>
    <p><a href="somePage'" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" role="button">I'm a button</a></p>

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.jumbotron { border: 1px solid #d4d4d4; background: transparent; padding: 10px; position: relative; }

.map { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; z-index: -1; }
```

hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an "overlay" element outside the map-canvas, and relative position it over the `jumbotron`...

```
#map-canvas {
  height:       450px;
  z-index:      -1;
}

#overlay {
  background:   #fff;
  opacity:      .8;
  position:     relative;
  top:          -300px;
  padding:      10px;
  z-index:      2;
  margin:       0 auto;
  width:        600px;
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

Demo: http://www.bootply.com/125543